# Storing an integer as an instance variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm so close on this one.  Basically what I'm trying to do is return the height of a cell for my UIWebView.  I've got the correct height printing out on my NSLOG.  The problem now is that I need to make a variable out of that height.  So far no luck.  Here is what I have right now.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
_descriptionWebView.frame = CGRectMake(_descriptionWebView.frame.origin.x, _descriptionWebView.frame.origin.y, _descriptionWebView.frame.size.width, 1);
CGSize fittingSize = [_descriptionWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
_descriptionWebView.frame = CGRectMake(_descriptionWebView.frame.origin.x, _descriptionWebView.frame.origin.y, _descriptionWebView.frame.size.width, fittingSize.height);

NSLog(@" Fitting Size is : %f", fittingSize.height);
}
```

It prints out the perfect size for each article that will display in the UIWebView (inside a UITableViewCell).  My main problem is how do I return that height in -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == SectionHeaderTitle) {

    // Regular
    return 54;

} else {

    return 612;
}
}
```

I've tried to make an instance variable out of fittingSize, using NSNumber, NSInteger, CGFloat, CGRect, CGSize...and basically I get "incompatible result type".

Ultimately what I want is to `return fittingSize.height;`

Any help on getting there?  Thank you very much in advance.  Hopefully I didn't leave anything out!

Comment: CGSize is a struct.  In theory you can make an instance variable out of it, but not a property.  Better to separately store the height and width, which are ordinary floats.

Comment: Show us your declaration for fittingSize, when you attempt to make it an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGSize.height is a CGFloat. Where are you getting the "incompatible result type"?

You should be able to declare a CGFLoat variable `CGFloat fittingHeight;` in your interface, then assign it in your -webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
_descriptionWebView.frame = CGRectMake(_descriptionWebView.frame.origin.x, _descriptionWebView.frame.origin.y, _descriptionWebView.frame.size.width, 1);
CGSize fittingSize = [_descriptionWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
_descriptionWebView.frame = CGRectMake(_descriptionWebView.frame.origin.x, _descriptionWebView.frame.origin.y, _descriptionWebView.frame.size.width, fittingSize.height);

fittingHeight = fittingSize.height;
}
```

Then use it in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: `    _fittingHeight = &fittingSize.height;` Is what it's suggesting I do.  

`        return fittingSize.height;` is giving me use of undeclared identifier 'fittingSize in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @Miles - You're not showing us something.  How are you trying to declare fittingSize?

Comment: @Miles That's because you declared fittingSize as a local variable in `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`, it's not accessible in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should declare a class variable `CGFloat fittingHeight` and store the height there, or declare `CGSize fittingHeight` a class variable in your interface (the .h).

Comment: in .h - `@property (nonatomic) CGFloat *fittingHeight;` 

in .m - `_fittingHeight = fittingSize.height;` which gives me an error "Assigning to 'CGFloat *'(aka 'float *') from incompatible type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float'); take the address with &

`_fittingHeight = &fittingSize.height;` is what it auto-fixes to, but when I try to return `_fittingHeight` in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` it also gives me an error Returning 'CGFloat *'(aka 'float *') from a function with incompatible result type 'CGFloat' (aka 'Float'); dereference with *

Comment: Storing a class variable of CGFloat worked.  Thanks for your patience!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Btw, another problem with your first declaration is that CGFloat is not an object, so do not declare it with a *.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class level variable of CGFloat type and in

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
      //Get the value of fittingsize.height
    }
```

save the value of fittingsize.height in that variable and use that variable in

```
    -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath
    {
      //Use the value stored of the CGFloat variable above
    }
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer as well.  Needs some upvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Forcefully cast it into a CGFloat like so:

```
return (CGFloat)(fittingSize.height);
```

Comment: fittingSize is a CGSize, so fittingSize.height is already a CGFloat. That cast does nothing.

Comment: Did you even try it? I can't imagine getting the same "incompatible result type" after returning an explicit CGFloat.